# Check if exists exactly one attribute of the node and return value of this attribute in XPAth

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I would like to check if exists attribute id and if it is not empty for this example xml file:

```
<component
    id="http://../EDYRA/prototype/TextEditor"
    isUI="true" 
    name="TextEditor"
    version="0.1">
    <binding>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency language="javascript">
                <url>https://../TextEditor.js</url>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <constructor>
            <code>new TextEditor();</code>
        </constructor>
    </binding>
</component>
```

I have wrote this XPath query in Java:

```
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//component[@id]/@id/text()");
Object result = expr.evaluate(file, XPathConstants.NODESET);
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;

resultsString += "Expression: //component[@id]/@id/text();
resultsString += " \r\nNode List: " + result.toString() + " \r\n Item: ";
resultsString += nodes.item(0) + " \r\n Length: ";
resultsString += nodes.getLength() + " \r\n\r\n\r\n";

file.getDocumentElement();
resultsString += "Attribute ->" + " : " + file.getDocumentElement().getAttribute("id");
```

I have tested it and unfortunately it returns list with 0 items:

*Expression: //component[@id]/@id/text()*

*Node List: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.DTMNodeList@4fe3c938*

*Item: null*

*Length: 0*

*Attribute -> http://../EDYRA/prototype/TextEditor*

How should look correct query to check if this attribute exists and get value of this attribute?

Edit:

//component[@id] also return no results. It looks like every query return nothing...

Comment: text() can't be apllied to attribute. Use such xpath `string(//component[@id]/@id)`.

Comment: surely, you can take attribute by `//component[@id]/@id` and take value by programm language, but i can't help with that in java

Comment: it also returns length 0 of the Node List

Comment: in php it works fine - https://eval.in/558602

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As well as omitting the text() access, you don't need to access @id twice. The expression `//component/@id` is precisely equivalent to `//component[@id]/@id` - it will return the @id attributes of all components that have such an attribute.

If you want to return the @id attribute only if it is non-empty, try `//component/@id[string()]`.

If `//component/@id` is returning nothing then there is something else going on that you haven't told us about - perhaps the component element is in a namespace?

Comment: Before the component element, which is a root node of my file, I have only: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>. I'm starting to think that maybe I did mistake in some other place of the code, while every XPath query returns nothing...

Comment: yep, it was problem with namespace

Answer (score 2):

> `//component[@id]/@id/text()`

An attribute cannot have children nodes, but in the above expression you want to select all text-node children of any selected `id` attribute. This incorrect expression will always select zero nodes.

One XPath expression that selects all `id` attributes (that have value) of all `component` elements in an XML document is:

```
//component/@id[string()]
```

In case you regard a white-space-only value as "empty" too, use this XPath expression:

```
//component/@id[normalize-space()]
```